# Determine if DST is in effect for a specified timezone given a time_t

Tags: c, timezone, dst

How could I determine if daylight savings time is in effect for a specified timezone given only a `time_t`?  I've [read](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html) that "In POSIX systems, a user can specify the time zone by means of the TZ environment variable."  I was thinking that I could save the current TZ value (if set), change it to the TZ I'm interested in, call `localtime()` and check `tm_isdst`, and change TZ back to it's original value.  I'm just not sure how portable that would be.

Is there a portable way to determine DST for a timezone given a `time_t` in C?

Comment: "portable way" --> No.  Highly portable (within POSIX) --> maybe.  As post is not tagged [POSIX] , unclear if you are seeking a POSIX answer or a portable (Standard C) one.

Comment: Can I ask *why* you want to know if DST is in effect?  Are you just planning on displaying something like, "hey user, did you know DST is in effect right now?" or is this one part in something more complex you are attempting?  Usually when I ask this, the answer is the latter, and the solution is to use a library, such as [CCTZ](https://github.com/google/cctz) or HHinnet's [date](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html) and [tz](http://howardhinnant.github.io/tz.html) libraries.

Comment: @chux I'm seeking portable, if possible.  As of now the code will be running in POSIX environments, but who knows what the future holds.

Comment: @MattJohnson I want to perform an operation at a specific time (Eastern/US) but the code will be running in a different timezone.  I'll look into those libraries.

Comment: Don't write anything into your code that depends on the time zone where the code is running unless you are actually intending to imply "local time", such as in a clock displayed to a user on a device.  In server-side code, and in many other cases, just take UTC time from the machine, and deal with time zone conversions on your own.  Also, use standard identifiers, `US/Eastern` is ok, but is a backwards compatible entry for `America/New_York` which is preferred.

Comment: But yes, if you're trying to compute time in a specific time zone - let the library figure out whether DST is a part of the calculation or not.  *You* shouldn't worry about that part.

Comment: I couldn't find any C libraries that deal with time zones (the above are C++).  I'm currently reinventing the wheel.  It baffles me that a language that has existed since the late 1960s / early 1970s hasn't yet included a mechanism to deal with time zones in a non-trivial way.

Answer (score 1):

This is as portable as I could make it.  I'd be interested in any better solution.  What I've done is calculate the time from epoch until the start and end of DST in the America/New_York time zone for a given year, and test if the given `time_t` falls in between.  This is specific to the America/New_York time zone but I would imagine that it could easily be adapted for another time zone, or adapted for any/all time zones, with some effort.

If using the GNU C Library, `timegm` can be used in place of `getenv`, `mktime`, `setenv`, *but* according to [GNU.org](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Broken_002ddown-Time.html):

> `mktime` is essentially universally available. `timegm` is rather rare.
>   For the most portable conversion from a UTC broken-down time to a
>   simple time, set the `TZ` environment variable to `UTC`, call `mktime`, then
>   set `TZ` back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

/***********************************************\
 * In America/New_York:
 * DST begins: second Sunday in March 02:00 local, after which EDT == UTC-04:00
 * DST ends: first  Sunday in November 02:00 local, after which EST == UTC-05:00
\***********************************************/

//Return 1 if the year at UTC is greater than the year in America/New_York at
//the given time t.  In other words, at time t, is it between 00:00:00 UTC 
//(midnight) Jan 1 and 05:00:00 UTC Jan 1.  Return 0 if the year at UTC is the 
//same as America/New_York at time t.
int UTCyearIsGreater(time_t when) {
    time_t begin, end;
    struct tm* tm;
    tm = gmtime(&when);
    if (tm->tm_mon == 11 && tm->tm_mday == 31 &&
            (tm->tm_hour >= 19 && tm->tm_hour < 5)) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

//Return number of seconds from epoch until DST begins/began in America/New_York, the second Sunday in March (ssim).
//for the given year.
time_t ssim(int year) {
    time_t t, t2;
    int sim = 0;
    struct tm tm = {0};
    tm.tm_year = year;
    tm.tm_mon = 2;
    tm.tm_mday = 1;
    tm.tm_hour = 7;
    char* env;
    env = getenv("TZ");
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    t = mktime(&tm);
    tm = *gmtime(&t);
    while (sim < 2) {
        if (tm.tm_wday == 0) {
            sim += 1;
            if (sim == 2) { break; }
        }
        tm.tm_mday += 1;
        tm.tm_wday = 0;
        t = mktime(&tm);
        tm = *gmtime(&t);
    }
    t = mktime(&tm);
    if (env == NULL) {
        unsetenv("TZ");
    } else {
        setenv("TZ", env, 1);
    }
    return t;
}

//Return number of seconds from epoch until DST ends/ended in America/New_York, the first Sunday in November (fsin).
//for the given year.
time_t fsin(int year) {
    time_t t;
    struct tm tm = {0};
    tm.tm_year = year;
    tm.tm_mon = 10;
    tm.tm_mday = 1;
    tm.tm_hour = 6;
    char* env;
    env = getenv("TZ");
    setenv("TZ", "UTC", 1);
    t = mktime(&tm);
    tm = *gmtime(&t);
    while (1) {
        if (tm.tm_wday == 0) { break; }
        tm.tm_mday += 1;
        tm.tm_wday = 0;
        t = mktime(&tm);
        tm = *gmtime(&t);
    }
    t = mktime(&tm);
    if (env == NULL) {
        unsetenv("TZ");
    } else {
        setenv("TZ", env, 1);
    }
    return t;
}

//Return 1 if DST is in effect in America/New_York at time t, return 0 otherwise
int DSTinNYC(time_t t) {
    time_t beginDST, endDST;
    struct tm* tm_ptr;
    tm_ptr = gmtime(&t);
    if (UTCyearIsGreater(t)) {
        tm_ptr->tm_year -= 1;
    }
    beginDST = ssim(tm_ptr->tm_year);
    endDST = fsin(tm_ptr->tm_year);
    return (t >= beginDST && t < endDST);
}

int main() {
    //test it
    if (DSTinNYC(1461179392)) { 
        printf("CORRECT 20 Apr 2016 15:09:52 EDT\n");
    } else {
        printf("FAILED 20 Apr 2016 15:09:52 EDT\n");
    }
    if (DSTinNYC(1455993975)) { 
        printf("FAILED 20 Feb 2016 13:46:15 EST\n");
    } else {
        printf("CORRECT 20 Feb 2016 13:46:15 EST\n");
    }
    if (DSTinNYC(1571179392)) { 
        printf("CORRECT 15 Oct 2019 18:43:12 EDT\n");
    } else {
        printf("FAILED 15 Oct 2019 18:43:12 EDT\n");
    }
    //results checked with http://www.epochconverter.com/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is also limited to the *current* set of DST transitions for New York.  The USA changed its rules last in 2007, but other countries change all the time.  This is why POSIX `TZ` variables are not good enough - they can only support two transitions, and can't handle year-over-year changes.  The [TZ database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) is essential to do this correctly.

Comment: BTW - Your code essentially recreates the effects of the POSIX TZ var of `EST5EDT,M3.2.0/2,M11.1.0/2`

Comment: True, but in the absence of a viable C library, what else could to do?

Comment: The GNU C library honors POSIX strings like the one I just mentioned.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/TZ-Variable.html

Comment: There are many other implementations listed here: https://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html  Perhaps one of those would work for your purposes.

Comment: Wow, the `TZ` environment variable is a lot more powerful than I gave it credit for.

Comment: Yes, but do understand, use of POSIX time zone strings is generally discouraged, because of their limitations.  See the POSIX section towards the bottom of the [timezone tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).  You should use a full tz database whenever possible, and preferably through one of the implementations already available.  Also note that the TZ project includes both data *and code* - you may just be able to use the tz code directly - depending on your particular setup.  http://www.iana.org/time-zones

Comment: @MattJohnson All I want is to generate a `time_t` representing the next occurrence of 8am America/New_York (preferably a solution that would survive political changes to DST rules).  I'm not a professional software developer so this is all mostly over my head.  Are you aware of any simple code examples that illustrate the use of this IANA database and that might help me get to where I want to go?

Comment: The reason this gets complicated is because you asked for a portable solution and not all systems have a tz database.  You either have to bring your own copy (like many libraries do - [ICU4C](http://site.icu-project.org/) is one example), or have platform-specific solutions (Windows in particular has a whole different set of data and APIs), or be limited to the POSIX formatted `TZ` variable, which has the limitations we've discussed here.